# Loading content based on a Select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, load

I have a screen that loads content dynamically. I'm using Jquery load(); method to fetch data on the same screen.

Now I have a combo box and this will control the content of the screen. For example: If I select a option on the drop-down, loads a file...

The combo-box is:

```
<select class="stock_combo">
  <option value="select">Select a corridor</option>
  <option value="1">A1</option>
  <option value="2">A2</option>
  <option value="3">A3</option>
</select>
```

A selected option, should do this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".dangerarea").load("dialogs/stock/corridor1.php");
    });
</script>


<div class="dangerarea">

[ .php filles will be loaded here. ]

</div>
```

How can I put this Javascript on each option to load it immediately?

Any help will be strongly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) for placing file content according to need

```
$(".stock_combo").on("change",function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
     $(".dangerarea").load("dialogs/stock/corridor" + selected + ".php");
});
```

Comment: Ok, but how to call it? I have to put some onClick code on each HTML option, right?

Comment: This will automatically fired as we have a `change()`. NO need to add click event on option. it will fire load file as soon as you select the option.

Comment: Understood. Each option needs to have the file name? I tried but didn't worked. <option value="corridor1">1</option>

Comment: The markup you posted in  the question is proper! if you want the markup like above you can do like `$(".dangerarea").load("dialogs/stock/" + selected + ".php")`

Comment: So each option has to have a value field having 1,2,3,4,5... and file name should be it's corresponding like file1, file2, file3, file4....